# Program that reads a csv, sums two columns, outputs to a new csv

Tags: java, csv

I haven't done java for 1-2 years so please bear with me. My project is to read a csv file that contains sales data. The data within the file includes a "Product ID" column and "Units Sold". I basically have to sum up the units sold with their respective Product ID and print it out with eliminating duplicate Product ID's to a new csv file.

Here is what I have so far, which reads the csv and prints out the data.

I'm essentially looking for answers or suggestions on where to go from here (not actual code). I'm thinking of putting each column into two different arrays, sorting by "Product ID" then adding units sold.

```
public class ReadCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCSV obj = new ReadCSV();
    obj.run();
  }

  public void run() {

    String csvFile = "C:/Users/Jeff/Desktop/SalesData.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] units = line.split(csvSplitBy);

            System.out.println(  units[1]+ 
                     " "+ units[2] + "");





        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

}
```

And here is some of my sample output:

```
Product ID Units
10002 4
10004 6
10008 2
10010 3
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might consider using something like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and generating some kind of POJO, which groups the data together, it would a simple matter of sorting these using a custom `Comparator` as needed

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking of putting each column into two different arrays

Use map instead. You can create `Map<Long, Product>`. Create `Product` class which can have attributes like `productId`, `units` if you have multiple attributes with unique `productId`. If you don't want to use map you can go with `List<Long>` for `productId` and `unit` and add every entry to this *two* different list.

> sorting by "Product ID" then adding units sold.

If you are using list then after loop use `list.sort()` to sort your list. You have to use `Long.parseLong` to convert `String` (`unit[0]` and `units[1]`) to `Long`.

> Sorry I should've specified that I think my instructions were to use arrays

Array should be initialized with fix width and remain same until you reinitialize the reference again. This is the main concern in your case. You can not be sure how many products will be there and if your file have fix number of lines or products you can use array, but still I suggest you to go with `List`  instead which internally uses array.

If you want to use array only you have to use large size. Say you have max `1000` products in your file you can initialize it as,

```
long productId[] = new long[1000];
```

Problem with array with max size is that it occupies lot of memory, which you should avoid to do.

Comment: Sorry I should've specified that I think my instructions were to use arrays

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm just trying to understand all of this since I haven't done this in a while. I don't even know how to start it to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the hashmap like below then iterate over the hashmap and write them to file

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        //Split and parse to int before
        if(map.get(productId) == null){
            map.put(productId,units);
        }
        else{
            map.put(productId, units + map.get(productId));
        }
    }
```